# Error: [0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 14.0.4.2 . When I enter the startup of the installation process, it stops at `[ 0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed` and even after a millennium of CPU cycles nothing happens.

What should I do or what am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I have read other similar questions on Superuser or StackOverflow but they all suggest that the error is not serious and that it should go away after a while, but it simply does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the file that opens add to the line that reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="?????????????"
```

Which following

```
clocksource=acpi_pm
```

To be well:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="?????????????clocksource=acpi_pm"
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, paste.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Then run:

```
update-grub
reboot
```

Comment: But the os  is not booting itself, how do I open an terminal? @kyodake

Comment: Boot in recovery mode

Comment: @kyodake During 14.04 installation from a DVD, the recovery mode is not visible among the options. what is to be done then?

Comment: Go to: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions