# install ubuntu on aspire one cloudbook 11

Tags: acer

i am trying to install ubuntu on a acer aspire one cloudbook 11, but i've got the below error: 
 Fast TSC calibration failed

if anyone can provides me help?

Comment: There are varrious things available on possible reasons (e.g. https://miguelmenendez.pro/en/articles/fast-tsc-calibration-failed-2.html ) and solutions (e.g. http://askubuntu.com/q/642008/178596). It seems it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error on many platforms, I think it can be safely ignored.